# Dog scraped up my wall and door

Tags: drywall

what should I do I have a steco in side I think it has a dry wall like da but looking on how to fix fast as it is a rental[image][image]

Comment: the second thing I noticed is that the trim is missing.

Comment: Camron, there are several significant phases to this repair, the first involving drywall and the second involving trim. Unfortunately your question is both broad and unclear. [We're not a discussion forum](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour). Please do some research into those two things and return when you have specific questions about the process or your particular case.

Comment: I've deleted pricing questions/comments since they are off topic for our site. Please keep questions to how to repair the damage, and then you can look into those costs with your local stores/contractors.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an easy DIY job. Get a utility knife, piece of drywall, a small bucket of drywall mud.
1. cut a perfect rectangular shape around the damaged drywall
2. cut the same size from your new drywall to be inserted
3. fit and use drywall screw to secure
4. mud
5. paint

I will advise going on youtube on how to repair drywall if you have no clue what I am talking about here...

Comment: There's also texture to consider, and trim procurement, finishing, and replacement. I think you've oversimplified a bit. To be fair, it's a poorly constructed question that should be closed.

Comment: either way, the steps remain the same. Once the drywall repair is done the texture is the easiest part of it. For me, this is a very simple fix but to be fair I am almost at the master level of DIY stuff. An associate from THD should be able to show a product that will give the same texture.

Comment: The texture may be easiest (I don't think it is), but you haven't addressed that at all. Your answer is at best incomplete.

Comment: Hence, the reason I suggest to get a consultation from an associate on what he/she can use to blend with the existing texture. I am sorry I don't work for Sherwin Williams or home depot (facepalm). I can't imagine that being so difficult once someone points him to the product.

maybe I should have mentioned taking a sample of the drywall that was removed to  the store but then again that's common sense.